# Same video with different url and resolution exoplayer

Tags: java, exoplayer2.x

I have same video but with different url and resolution. How can I change video quality on exoplayer?. I'm sorry my question may seem unclear and you ask me to use mu38 manifest but that's not posible since I have created the web app using html5 and html5 support creating media source with different url and different resolution, but exoplayer only support dash and mu38 for quality change which is bad for me and my partner cos we can't change existing content and database structure. **Is there a way for me to change quality providing different mp4 URL on exoplayer?**

I currently thought of using hls manifest , but how can I do this without having to create mu38 .ts chunk files? CHECK my current MU38 Pseudocode

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:Sun Jan 09 2022 00:01:26 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=640000, CODECS="MPEG4", RESOLUTION=1920x1080
http://localhost:3000/video.mp4
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=840000, CODECS="MPEG4", RESOLUTION=1280x720
http://localhost:3000/video.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most players will only switch resolutions on segment boundaries, i.e. at the end of one segment and the start of the next.

For your case you essentially just have one large segment for your entire video so this will not help you.

If you really must use just the two separate complete files with different resolutions you might find it is possible to use two instances of exoplayer but only show one at a time. This would (in theory) allow you start, for example, the higher resolution video at a point in the timeline to match the currently playing lower resolution video and then switch or fade between them - i.e. make the new higher resolution visible and hide and stop the lower resolution version.

I don't think this will be easy however, either to exactly match the timing, or to achieve a switch without some obvious visual indication to the user.

I am not sure also that I fully followed your comment about web app creation, but just in case it is not clear you can support DASH, and HLS, streams in a web app by using a player like VideoJS. This will handle reading the HLS or DASH manifest and streams and build the segments into something that regular the browser underlying video player can work with.

Comment: Not original owner of content, I'm streaming torrent file using webtorrent then pipe out using Nodejs readStream. I have torrentURI of different URI, streaming URI format "http://localhost:3000/stream?torrent=mytorrentURI&resolution=720p".           If Content was originally mine , I would have used ffmpeg to covert to dash chunks , but I have to stream torrent files with different resolution at runtime , that's why I have to create hls manifest at runtime for exoplayer to parse.